# Is it a brainfuck instruction?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, brainfuck

A very simple challenge today. Output a truthy value whether the ASCII character (or it's code) supplied is a brainfuck instruction (one of `+-,.<>[]`), and a falsy value if it's a comment (everything else).

### Input

```
+
#
<
>
.
P
,
```

### Output

```
true
false
true
true
true
false
true
```

Comment: As in, can the answer be formatted as either a program or function? (such as requiring `main(){}` and all of that in C answers)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms doesn't matterdoesn't matter

Comment: Is the input character guaranteed to be printable ASCII? (32-126)

Comment: No, but I'd like to see (a part of an already valid answer) that assumes it's printable as an "addon". As I've stated (or rather deleted the comment afterwards), as it's quite a boring challenge, I'm looking for some creativity

Comment: Shouldn't the language name be capitalized?

Comment: @LuisMendo No, according to the [esolang wiki](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), it's often lowercase

Comment: +8/-6, now that's a controversy :p

Comment: +10/-7 is this challenge *that* bad?

Answer (score 21):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>105</s> <s>103</s> 95 bytes

Outputs `\x00` for false and `\x01` for true.

```
,>>>+++++++[<++++++<++++>>-]<+[<<->>-]<<[-[-[-[--------------[--[>+[<->-]<[--[<->[-]]]]]]]]]<+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx87OThsCom0gNJiys9ONtQEK2eiCWTbRuhCIAoDcaDugIl2QEhAHyIrWjYUBG229//9jAQ)

The general principle is comparing against all values (decreasing partial distances of the char-codes), using loops to logically `OR` the results, and if none matched - change the output cell from `1` to `0`.

See my [`4` answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203339/65326) for a more detailed explanation (`4` instructions read more easily).

Answer (score 12):

## [unsure](https://github.com/Radvylf/unsure), 1302 bytes

```
um um yeah err hm yeah uhhhhhhhh then ummmm uhhh errrr uhh errr ummmmm yeah err uh then heh then err um heh but um um yeah err heh no oops then but oops heh oops oops oops oops oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhhhhhh no oops oops then um err uh then heh then err um heh but um um yeah err heh no oops then but oops heh oops oops oops oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhhhhh no oops oops then um err uh then heh then err um heh but um um yeah err heh no oops then but oops heh oops oops oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhhhh no oops oops then um err uh then heh then err um heh but um um yeah err heh no oops then but oops heh oops oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhhh no oops oops then ummmmmmm uh errr uh then heh then err um heh but um um yeah err heh no oops then but oops heh oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhh no oops oops then umm err uh then heh then err um heh but um um yeah err heh no oops then but oops heh oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhh no oops oops then ummmmmm uhhh ummmmm errrrrr uh then heh then err um heh but um um yeah err heh no oops then but oops heh oops oops um then heh then uhhh no oops oops then umm err uh then heh then err um heh but um um yeah err heh no oops then but oops heh oops um then heh then uhh no oops oops oops okay
```

This was not easy. Unsure is a new stack based language I've created, that uses words people tend to say when they're not sure about something.

It's kind of hard to explain how such a large program works, but I'll try to give a high-level explanation. First, here's an expanded version of this program:

```
um um yeah err hm yeah uhhhhhhhh then ummmm uhhh errrr uhh errr ummmmm yeah err uh

then heh then err um heh
but um um yeah err heh no oops then
but oops heh oops oops oops oops oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhhhhhh no oops oops then um err uh

then heh then err um heh
but um um yeah err heh no oops then
but oops heh oops oops oops oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhhhhh no oops oops then um err uh

then heh then err um heh
but um um yeah err heh no oops then
but oops heh oops oops oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhhhh no oops oops then um err uh

then heh then err um heh
but um um yeah err heh no oops then
but oops heh oops oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhhh no oops oops then ummmmmmm uh errr uh

then heh then err um heh
but um um yeah err heh no oops then
but oops heh oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhh no oops oops then umm err uh

then heh then err um heh
but um um yeah err heh no oops then
but oops heh oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhh no oops oops then ummmmmm uhhh ummmmm errrrrr uh

then heh then err um heh
but um um yeah err heh no oops then
but oops heh oops oops um then heh then uhhh no oops oops then umm err uh

then heh then err um heh
but um um yeah err heh no oops then
but oops heh oops um then heh then uhh no oops oops

oops okay
```

The first part sets up the stacks. There are two stacks, one of which is selected as the active stack. The first stack contains a `0` at the bottom (the return value), as well as 8 copies of the input character's ASCII character code, negated.

After this, there are 8 sections to check for equality (first one shown as an example):

```
then heh then err um heh
but um um yeah err heh no oops then
but oops heh oops oops oops oops oops oops oops oops um then heh then uhhhhhhhhh no oops oops then um err uh
```

The first line will pop the first stack and add it to the first, which in this case is `43` (the character code for `+`). It also pushes `1` to the first stack. The next line is essentially an if statement, which is used to create a NOT operator by pushing `0` to the first stack if the result of adding the character code is not `0` (meaning they are not the same).

The third line is the most complicated. It starts with a sort of else statement, as it only runs when the second line's if statement doesn't push `0` (and therefore the character code was 43). It will then replace the bottom of the first stack with `1`, the new output.

Finally, after the "else statement", the character code is incremented to 44, for `,`, and the process is repeated 7 times.

The last line, `oops okay`, just outputs the bottom item in the first stack, as the previous operations have cleared it out except for one copy of the input (`oops` discards the top of the stack, and `okay` outputs).

There's definitely a few bytes I could golf here and there, might work on it later.

Comment: um err uh okay uh well then um uh yeah um sure

Comment: Why is `like` not in there?

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Not sure how to answer (luckily this language gives me lots of options to express that :p)

Answer (score 11):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 9 bytes

```
[]+-.<>[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPzpWW1fPxi469v9/bS5lLhsuOy49rgAuHQA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: This is actually a character class; the outer `[]`s delimit the class, as (by being placed immediately after the opening `[`) the first `]` is actually part of the class. The `,` isn't needed as the `-` creates a range from `+` to `.` which helpfully includes the `-` itself as well as the `,`.

Comment: I am now worried that the stuff that parses regular expressions is actually a backtracking regex engine...

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 16 bytes

```python
'+-,.<>[]'.count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfpmAb819dW1dHz8YuOlZdLzm/NK/kf3lGZk6qgqFVQVFmXolCmkZRYnl8Zl5BaYmGpuZ/bS5lLhsuOy49rgAuHS4A)

An anonymous method is shorter here than a `lambda`. See my tip [Object method as answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95156/20260).

Comment: `<built-in method count of str object at 0x101520730>`?

Comment: The str object "at 0x101520730" is the string literal in the program. It has a built-in method named `count`. This method will return `1` only if given an instruction character. You can call it in the normal way by providing an immediate parameter e.g. `('.')` or you can assign it to a variable (e.g. `f`) and call `f` later.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Note also that the usual submissions of `lamdba`'s are represented as a similarly weird value like `<function <lambda> at 0x7fd4f39d7758>`.

Comment: Anything that doesn't have a `__str__` or a `__repr__` has that.

Answer (score 7):

### [vJASS](https://wc3modding.info/pages/vjass-documentation/) ([Warcraft 3](https://playwarcraft3.com/en-us/)), <s>299</s> <s>278</s> 265 bytes

Using `//! import zinc "<code_path>"` command to exclude `//! zinc` and `//! endzinc`.

---

Prints T (True) and F (False).

```c
library Q{trigger W=CreateTrigger();integer E;function onInit(){TriggerRegisterPlayerChatEvent(W,Player(0),"",false);TriggerAddAction(W,function(){for(0<=E<8){if(GetEventPlayerChatString()==SubString("+-<>.,[]",E,E+1)){BJDebugMsg("T");return;}}BJDebugMsg("F");});}}
```

---

**Readable Version:**

```c
library CodeGolf{
    trigger chatEvent = CreateTrigger();
    integer Index;

    function onInit(){
        TriggerRegisterPlayerChatEvent(chatEvent, Player(0), "", false);
        TriggerAddAction(chatEvent, function(){
            for (0 <= Index < 8){
                if(GetEventPlayerChatString() == SubString("+-<>.,[]", Index, Index + 1)) {
                    BJDebugMsg("T");
                    return;
                }
            }
            BJDebugMsg("F");
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

+1 due to a bug fix noted by @Kevin Cruijssen

-1 thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

```
"+-,.<["ºIå
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fSVtXR88mWunQLs/DS///jwYA)

an interesting approach, but sadly it's longer and it doesn't work:

```
•q”;ιÚ•2ôIÇ;îå
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOiwkcNc63P7Tw8C8g2OrzF83C79eF1h5f@/x8NAA)

Comment: Your 11-byter should be `"+-,.<>[]"Iå` or `"+-,.<>[]"så`. You want to check if the input is in that string, not if that string is in the input. And you can save a byte by using the mirror builtin: [`"+-,.<["ºIå`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fSVtXR88mWunQLs/DS///jwUA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 18 bytes

```hs
(`elem`"+-.,<>[]")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYlBDoIwEADv@4oNXiBAXwC9eDbhrkY2uIXG7drYvt9aTzOTOSi9WKQ4nPFW2pWFw9r0oxkme703XQnktb6d8/mtmTUntHbGQPHywPjxmtH8C1tX5WB6dpXilVPp4QQTWDCwwPDdnNCeyrjF@AM)

Low-effort unnamed function.

Comment: For convenience with pointfree TIO submissions, you can add the `-cpp` flag and use backslash to continue a line like this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBDoIwEEDR/ZxighsI0BPQblybsFcjE5xC43RsbM9vxdV/f6f8YpHq0d5qu7BwXJp@NMPkrvemq5GCosWNy/mthbVkdM5ipHR5YPoELWj@h60/sDM9u6MSlHPt4QQTODAww/BdvdCW67im9AM "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor ah I tried to do that without the flag, ty

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>26</s>, 23 bytes

```python
lambda s:s in'+-,.<>[]'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmAb8z8nMTcpJVGh2KpYITNPXVtXR8/GLjpW/X9BUWZeiUaaRmZeQWmJhqam5n9tAA)

Comment: Is this really a valid format?

Comment: @dingledooper , I might have gotten mixed up. I'm pretty new, still don't know all the valid formats. The only reason I changed this from my old answer was because I saw xnor's answer, which I thought was invalid, but, hey - he's way more experienced than me, so I probably just didn't know something. Am changing back to my old one.

Comment: For your information, xnor's answer is still a function, in that it can be called with a parameter. Your previous answer was not, it was just a snippet since `in` is a keyword that doesn't make a function

Comment: @Dion See also my tip [Object method as answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95156/20260).

Comment: This isn't a valid answer; it's an expression, not a function.

Answer (score 3):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 131 bytes

Outputs `\x00` for false, `\x01` for true.

```
3.799600006010160202614146292964343199994389919999018991999901899199990189919999148991999902899199992989919999028995004999999995014
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fchBCoBADEPRAwmStJlq7n@wOgwquPGvHl/duR92YVYgWAhEUVSFw6VU0jPlaS@Bf6LeF4/CnzcA@W6A6t4u)

### Explanation

**4 doesn't have a simple comparison or condition instructions**, so I used while-not-zero loops to fake them and match by distances:

```
3.

6 00 00            # set constants
6 01 01 
6 02 02 
6 14 14 
6 29 29 
6 43 43 

7 99               # input as integer

1 99 99 43 - 8 99  # for each brainfuck character
1 99 99 01 - 8 99  # compare to the input,
1 99 99 01 - 8 99  #  (subtracting differences to the input)
1 99 99 01 - 8 99  #  and jump to the end if true,
1 99 99 14 - 8 99  #  otherwise start a loop (to fake branching)
1 99 99 02 - 8 99 
1 99 99 29 - 8 99 
1 99 99 02 - 8 99 
5 00 4             # if all comparisons failed, print 'false' and exit
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9    # close loops

5 01 4             # print 'true' and exit
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 28 bytes

```c
f(c){c=index("+-,.<>[]",c);}
```

No math here, no math there, no math anywhere.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxDoIwFEX3fsXLMyStLcSZAm7ODm7qQB4gTbSYAkZC@PZaiHe5yT25h@IHkfcNJzFTbmxVfznKWCVZcb2jIqEXb@wAr9JY/ulMJdjMIITa0sHeWMgB5S4rkrNCzTbUdI7rgLSxUoptWvN2QdRwjCiFqL9ZVOtfQcNDCTgCXtw4tBNCCngqn/2E4m909TA6CwfNFv8D)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 3 bytes

Built-ins FTW!

```
~B{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6jMTv3/v86p@v9/JW0lAA)

## Explanation

```
~B  "><+-.,[]"
  { Does it contain input?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$10\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 8.231 bytes

```
Ix"[]-=.,"
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJJeFwiW10tPS4sXCIiLCIsIl0=)

<s>An answer so the bot can get 30 rep to chat.</s> Never mind, realized I had enough on SF&F, but deleting this would be useless, so here ya go.

Answer (score 3):

## 6502 assembly, 17 bytes

```
0000: 69 05 29 FD A2 04 D5 0C
0008: F0 03 CA D0 F9 60 30 31
0010: 41
```

This subroutine should be called with A set to the input, and the carry flag cleared. It will return with the Z flag indicating whether the input was a Brainfuck instruction.

Here the subroutine is at `$0000` but it can go anywhere on the zero page. The asterisk in `cmp *r-1,x` forces a 2-byte zero-page-based comparison (in [this web assembler](https://www.masswerk.at/6502/assembler.html), at least).

```
.org $0000
f:
  adc #5
  and #$fd
  ldx #4
loop:
  cmp *r-1,x
  beq r
  dex
  bne loop
r:
  rts  ; which is #$60
.byte $30, $31, $41
```

### How it works

The valid Brainfuck instructions are {2b, 2c, 2d, 2e, 3c, 3e, 5b, 5d} in hexadecimal. Adding 5 to the ASCII values groups them into pairs like "n or n+2" where the second-lowest bit doesn't matter:

| Instruction | ord+5 | Bit pattern |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `+` or `-` | `$30` or `$32` | 0011 00x0 |
| `,` or `.` | `$31` or `$33` | 0011 00x1 |
| `<` or `>` | `$41` or `$43` | 0100 00x1 |
| `[` or `]` | `$60` or `$62` | 0110 00x0 |

This means we can check if `(n+5)&~2` ∈ {`$30`, `$31`, `$41`, `$60`}.

Actually a lot of choices other than `5` work. But this one puts `$60` in the set of values to look for, which is the opcode for the `RTS` instruction. Thus we can interleave the table with the final instruction and save one byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rt`, 10 bytes

```
-`[]+-,.<>
```

This:

- Pushes the string `[]+-,.<>` onto the stack
- Subtracts that string from the input.

If it is a BF instruction, an empty string will be printed, otherwise, the input character will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 26 bytes

```
print(input()in"+-,.<>[]")
```

Comment: You need something to output the result, usually `print`. See the [Python I/O summary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11925/20260).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use `exit` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 43 bytes

```
1\left\{42<i<47,i=60,i=62,i=91,i=93\right\}
```

[Try it online](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gcyjw2zlqh)

Desmos doesn't support strings, so this turns from relatively trivial string comparison to relatively trivial integer comparison. I tried to compress the higher numbers, but I couldn't find a nice way to exclude 61 and 92, and the sequence doesn't show up in OEIS.

Comment: Where exactly can we test desmos answers at? Please do provide a link in later submissions.

Comment: @Razetime You can test Desmos answers at the link provided at Desmos (note: I accidentally put the wrong one for this question, fixing that as well). I didn't bother to generate a specific link for this answer as it's trivial, but I probably should have. Adding it now.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kŻ$Ƈ
```

**11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md):**

```
"[]<>-+.,"$Ƈ
```

**14 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md):**

```
»ÐṘWĠœṪɲ»ɦBCsƇ
```

**16 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md):**

```
C¿€ỵæ-j2oẹ&⁵ẏ¿sƇ
```

Due to a bug with the `Ƈ` command (which will be fixed in 2.2.0), the `s` is needed in the last two answers. They will both be one byte less in 2.2.0.

#### Explanations

```python
kŻ$Ƈ  # Implicit input
  $   # The input...
   Ƈ  # ...is in...
kŻ    # ...the string "[]<>-+.,"
      # Implicit output
```

```python
"[]<>-+.,"$Ƈ  # Implicit input
          $   # The input...
           Ƈ  # ...is in...
"[]<>-+.,"    # ...the string "[]<>-+.,"
              # Implicit output
```

```python
»ÐṘWĠœṪɲ»ɦBCsƇ  # Implicit input
»ÐṘWĠœṪɲ»       # Compressed integer 4344454660629193...
         ɦB     # ...converted to base 100 as a list...
           C    # ...and converted to ordinals...
            sƇ  # ...contains the input
                # Implicit output
```

```python
C¿€ỵæ-j2oẹ&⁵ẏ¿sƇ  # Implicit input
C                 # The ordinal of the input...
              sƇ  # ...is in...
 ¿€ỵæ-j2oẹ&⁵ẏ¿    # ...the compressed list [43, 44, 45, 46, 60, 62, 91, 93]
                  # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: ... _why_ is `kŻ` a built-in?!

Comment: @Shaggy Vyxal has `kT` for the same thing as well. I didn't know what else to add as a constant, and I had one space left, so I added it :p

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-¡`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 63 bits / 7.875 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
o"+,-.<>[]
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LaE&code=byIrLC0uPD5bXQ&input=Iisi)

(Because, apparently, we're scoring in bits now? ‍♂️)

Comment: [Vyxal can be scored in bits because it has a compression algorithm](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode) that generates a string of bits. It's exclusive to Vyxal, and not language agnostic at all.

Answer (score 2):

## 6502 Machine-Language, 32 bytes

```
0000: AD 1E 00 A2 00 DD 15 00
0008: D0 04 EE 1F 00 00 E8 EC
0010: 1D 00 D0 F1 00 3C 3E 2B
0018: 2D 2E 2C 5B 5D 08 50 00
```

The above "ROM" includes the variables and the program.
Here's a basic breakdown:

```
0000: AD 1D 00 A2 00 DD 14 00    Program
0008: D0 04 EE 1E 00 00 E8 EC
0010: 1C 00 D0 F1 00
                     3C 3E 2B    Brainfuck instructions
0018: 2D 2E 2C 5B 5D 08          ("<>+-.,[]" and an 8 for the length)
                        50 00    Input char and output byte
```

You can try it out using [This online emulator](https://www.masswerk.at/6502/)
by copying the above ROM into the "RAM" field and setting the input byte (`0x001D`)
to the desired character in hexadecimal. Then you can load it into memory by pressing "Load Memory", then press "Show Memory" to confirm it loaded and
check the box "live update" so it will show the result once it's done.
Finally, you can press "Continuous Run" and it will write the result to the last
byte of the ROM (`0x001E`). `0x01` for true and `0x00` for false.

Assembly Code:

```
.ORG $0000

; PROGRAM

  LDA INPUT
  LDX #0
loop:
  CMP CHARS,X
  BNE end
  INC OUTPUT
  BRK
end:
  INX
  CPX CHARSLEN
  BNE loop
  BRK

; DATA

CHARS:
  .ASCII "<>+-.,[]"
CHARSLEN:
  .BYTE 8
INPUT:
  .ASCII "P"
OUTPUT:
  .BYTE 0
```

To summarise, it basically reads the input character into the accumulator
and then loops over the list of Brainfuck instructions using the X register
and if Acc matches any of the chars it increments the output byte and exits.

It's probably not very good and could also probably be smaller, but I'm not very experienced with 6502 assembly and just wanted to give it a go.
Feedback welcome :)

(I also haven't tested it very thoroughly so it might also not work in some cases)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

*-2 thanks to @Arnauld*

```javascript
c=>/[+-.<>[\]]/.test(c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyxDoIwEMbx3ae4ibSpFHVxgLLwCI7I0JwUIXhn2sbF@Oz1ti/55ftv/uMTxvWda@LHXIIr6PpmNLXt@vE@TY3Nc8oKdQkcFYGDUwsEHZwvVxnGaPgeAFDgluNKiw2RX8PTx0F6inQrGuQPVQXIlHif7c6LoiOg4K/8AQ)

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcyxDoIwEMbx3ae4ibSpFHVxgLLwCI7I0JwUIXhn2sbF@Oz1ti/55ftv/uMTxvWda@LHXIIr6PpmNLXt@vE@TY3Nc8oKdQkcFYGDUwsEHZwvVxnGaPgeAFDgluNKiw2RX8PTx0F6inQrGuQPVQXIlHif7c6LoiOg4K/8AQ)

Comment: @Arnauld Forgot about `.test`, thanks!

Comment: You can just use `/[+-.<>[\]]/.test` - [point-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)

Comment: @pxeger Doesn't work. Try `f=/[+-.<>[\]]/.test` then `f("[")`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms wow I should never under-estimate the stupidity of JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 45 bytes

```
 "<>[]+-,." INPUT :F(F)
 X =1
F OUTPUT =X
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/X0HJxi46VltXR09JwdMvIDREwcpNw02TSyFCwdaQy03BPzQEJGgbweXq5/L/vx4A)

1 for truthy, empty line for falsey.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
/"+-,.<>[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X19JW1dHz8YuOvb/fyVdJQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 18 bytes

```
{it in "+-<>[].,"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@1@WmKOQlGaloOGckVikqaBrp@CUn5@TmpinYPu/OrNEITNPQUlb18YuOlZPR6n2f1ppnkJuYmaehqaCrUJBUWZeiUZSmoa6trqm5n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala 2.12, 15 bytes

```scala
"<>+-.,[]"toSet
```

This takes the string of all brainf*** instructions and turns it into a set. Since Scala's sets are also predicates, we can treat it like a function that returns `true` when it's a valid instruction.

Scala 2.12 is required for postfix operator `toSet`.

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1zTvpQDQTi2KAQ1iaSUS5Q)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [9 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
[‚‚◄┴´£Q7
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=IistLiw8PltdIiY=&input=Kw==)

## Explained

Unpacked: `"+-.,<>[]"&`

```
  "+-.,<>[]" Literal string
& Contains element
  _ Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ẇ“+-<>[],.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrvZHDXO0dW3somN19P4/apjLZX24XdP9/38lZSUdBSVtJQA)

### How it works

```
ẇ“+-<>[],. - Main link. Takes a character C on the left
 “+-<>[],. - Yield "+-<>[],."
ẇ          - Is C in that string?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Red, 27 bytes

```
""= exclude input"+-,.<>[]"
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! Would you mind editing in a link to an online interpreter such as [TryitOnline](https://tio.run/##K0pN@f9fSclWIbUiOac0JVUhM6@gtERJW1dHz8YuOlYJKKmtBAA), so that other's can test and verify your code?

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 11 bytes

```
`[]+-.<>,`c
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%60%5B%5D%2B-.%3C%3E%2C%60c&inputs=%5B&header=&footer=)

More interestingly,

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 13 bytes

```
C₁»½¤Ǎ⋏⟨꘍ċ»τc
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=C%E2%82%81%C2%BB%C2%BD%C2%A4%C7%8D%E2%8B%8F%E2%9F%A8%EA%98%8D%C4%8B%C2%BB%CF%84c&inputs=%5B&header=&footer=)

```
C             # Get charcode
 ₁»½¤Ǎ⋏⟨꘍ċ»τ  # Base-100 list of valid charcodes
            c # Is included?
```

Comment: [`kTc`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBcj0iLCIiLCJrVGMiLCIiLCIrXG4jXG48XG4+XG4uXG5QXG4sIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 14 bytes

```julia
in("+-,.<>[]")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/M09DSVtXR8/GLjpWSfN/Wn6RQqZCZp4CXFA5wNDIWN/KWomroCgzryQnTyNTwdZOIU0jU1OTKzUv5T8A)

some Julia functions will return an anonymous function when fed with not enough arguments, basically `in(x) = y -> in(y,x)`. It would be a bit more interesting with `∈` but it costs 1 more byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem) (pxem.mktemp.emb.posixism, `BREAK_LOOP_WHEN_INSUFFICIENT=1`), filename only: 33 bytes.

The `\0001` is an unprintable whose codepoint is 0x01.

```
[<>+-,.].i.t@.w.m.-\0001.yT.o.d.a.c.a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pTp7X@LIsv/nU/REFCIkAXRGR4yz6KDDGQWP4p3ZI05@MTQShYRNB8EH96vvrerOG2d2z152ZUjXo6vr1VWdfrLY6M@1d/qt4@psJElrZLqgE23yENDJVKOTW23qMWfhsIlGHFe1vQEl54ABDwH1pz6Fb01aA7pjagUznzJ4Iio58iZTK3Bux5TMnWBE3AetyDiRO6ADwqZ06AwdG1A8lxMcPgVUnblOQOyR5Vs28OXjHY@wMQhJXM8n7mw8JkP4MXTG1LUmlKNcBj61JqrnOxT4D0hb73KJvvlOAPOR2yeN9KYWPbbmz9RF@Y4d1xqT2XRgBVQj9Wq9plV3tK0aueodlT8ixqljU5cB8Ah4B84jxRVNPJeR/1DfI49AoKG27mhAzruX7e/jJ8JmoBCH0TFljFD30fE9dwIiSQyQVDqTZhOLPZBqdWeHrMF6AvhZrzeIxfiahM4luph6fkBOj8zm6alxJAVPU4rT2J47JAf6gD7qXA31g40a2dgQcBuEs9zBW/CQ33mz98WQC6UIU53GTBEE6DGpUnjBofLeUvxQl3LE5arT/m5e9j4b9Wp1CxaBcn85V6@@x9OgLk5/N4@6Fxeto55RC5FOOld/rpHzqx75vXt1Qc6/t87IJfw6apEvrYuWdNw@bXWaZy2jeL1/UFYr2o3maMFv2lybaGq/Wq3WtKee5mkDzdJszSpKR91Or9XpGcDVHlH7wXHvEq9whhIhBIzhBkOyzvp9l8iFaAqZvCL0zqdTov5B1Bbp4zN8iqUfr9c/@v0bpd8vVV@r@D//qyql6x9VdffmtaAUiRSMqIsk1B55pIPKjn0WXDwWg9QONuocbwFuXZOGjvTPJdNf08K933mt4h98pURTilnRLnng/IVEoD9v5gYgk3fnWxMJrbVAorRcciHUt5wajscaZOCll3ULSAtYDJnbRLXFpAPPpZJwVuHoK776@kpekIsAl5RSuHYePUfhw8Dxg8kUHPmld3b@uX2xh84pQLbFKEwsMGRcQalYVEJgQqrDVzjYaJT0NxC0BLy5Coapxa91PZ660aDMssMHnp@4tkGEQrSKUsLIGZJrovqEr3/mQzR6E3IDsYrDdm64QSKTxh8PordJXKIGZLBN1A6Br8cMWYJOx4xmiEtThtSqR6bOoEIDZ0IrU3s6qzyyZ7AjJERFeOFb0834TFlw4IN1GKnW6lvb7z/s7H4kxeu@u3lTzOFxr9byxJYzJqpLtus5AIM8XmT6D22zX9L6L7v9ZV8p6P2anmdrzR9QJstQ67Xtne3drQ/bu6SYQXmxykah2li2Op9fuIsSa5nCgCAQP5KFI9PiS4LCUK2lQlVppMjQxOCbhmzd2gM6vBs59w/jietN//BZMHucL56em4dHn1vHJ1/a//p6etbpnv/74rJ39T/fvv/@n0RdppxiempAoN4Fo1LEPTOj55cco9Zw9o1ateGUy8pLZp0Ivwf4PcC3G/cAz4CTAGWzWxb48RwVGCzxFSqbp0qllp4zIiJyWsxl@DNWoxKlAPHZIwdxJOoFPo@Me1FekCgB/gITKoyZ75JqFP@YRkLXxhQni2yxR4bgSeAzgQfbmkt98GNiEQR5vuU/8Qwox@kv4VvDR0VaSpI9ppZrghhciJLQLc89Kim81CDRkMIniTu8NSXFIml9b/fIl6tz0u70yL@v4OG8fd4izdOLM9JrXZwhrj8h6hAWGLGVYwbq36LnebpQA/kiDriHizUrcri3orcy23emgcRZZ1fy1/NIUIaRg4OUlGR/vwjJ/bh9UpQOWyftDlfG1WXLPDwyqtwRDi9aza/mabd7bn770uqY7c7l1fFx@6iNm3KNozQPuxc98/Ci@xXgiJkZb5@etk6ap0DYa520LhC2lMSkIBGUj2Cx0ArpfaUWbpLprFSLs9JKMkL/yuSjdBpaI55/Z7nOMyVjBzZvqAkhLqCSEECf2t4dhz5aYwd96wFqQilJOp@7PWP7g8g2iZrgM2ZAFSoKd6bJ4LpWq98Y@GO3emPIUzkLqwnYzkeAeTlYNYTtAszNwqrvQ9gWwJwM7COAZDM79FFgf9gBkJ2bJeS0i5xYDrYbwj4A7DEnQbiqHVzVMAcLV/UBV0VzPLdDnkAv@zlYKOcuyjnPwuqhNnZRG4scLJxvF@d7ysFCOT@inM9ZteyEYqLGrJwoH0KWIK4c5JYXirmDYk5ysFDMDyjmIAPbRg2Xs0M4s5oZ2kKsd9khVH8hO4RTr8dDwh/5E8/QkTtCm/boeDNmhF5@zf3zJiKLRstlMY6bpRSVKqWY2AD2GxuFKpY1MHl688Gdh9OqRr3Bf4hvVVVWt5KhHAXb@qDvypW3hYo3HlxnoRqPL@PV4XaelFyln877dyddFqOsMB859oh4Q4J7OGw5lMFeMrECGMRm9pPAotqdRuZksVjgTuNFP@cCCkWeJUix0ePEFV7KEaZbelMn2IQ5d9DVUjKc@QDxBSHzSBNUPMDmGKhvfcw6xEqlHZeyYPxoVEXi0X9co5g3BT3SBp8MBQWLCty0Sbk6Gi5dBImj6D@shBxsHs5gVNNG5oRyU27wTamaMUia7GCVaihb6zaqPRFN4Kpq2uCxUBk71xqxYazBgIytWyhq@bMYbJ@1e81eu3NCTrq9LrmEh9YZ7EKX5FsbGtvj7ulp9xuCm9@@kstO@/y81dsTpNxvGkLcNbEGzt6A3LJYyMoLfC8jIJbSv8bQNC2NzGHw1POdsDLx8NuFEmbhsAA7Vs5L0CxTS3JcJ3Cs8fgJyi4xAu4BBQ38jbw58Ak8FcjDVXAvRXeChp5zhQAFfyJjz4PCiOkFvaLnMLnjIWqCRzjmbyGmNbcW8ydLYNueC3xnWXymV37bTFgjgRUR3PrUelhlzwmiGZp7qAzc6Mc0oLDUgTMcwioh5MMab410D3vfoggQbHDpoME56iMKidT@K2wjy0t@wCLUC25F8cxJnBtBbU6mlh8Iz3o7gIRvlsuRL0K9XILMW8H/OEslE0xEFvPIYr5MWL3NWlUzrFEvwPu3v889jghQBdaTLhtjxRse7jDUrDWFjh444DgolElRVyUkE0xjuZiuL/MOrsewgg6eHj3eptYXJdU0n@mMjUppWmWVEjq7aUGHPAs13juoZYOnkqJMZwGeo5SmHnT/ggjwvIIOMv0FkruChEeNdzSP5xSEeHj0hVwSiJlAItIEaOfZA2KQYcxyGAiMYI8FHfZQ6jOajA0LeqqdwwADxzf5DoaNHZ8hHL12bmIyWtDBY3wP15fi5r8hX6qpEzqIsSOfRFNDUJkwz6Akb8iK8oajc6eIx2MXjXhZ/ZJgh@15lmG/FnEM/fstpnnXj/g2C3oYy5/kRph/aAQMsssNvBG1pjlLTzgOB4QKGfreJHyOkAYFnaeqWDPld4V1VagGbVFSDoy6YvmwYU3AL2yuJY4cByBwHIBpedobeh6EA4@0UnwIV@TFUZiXcLNJRRhEFQ9H2OoTfC5RHIwrTZRi3Xp@YKKiBR9FdOG8iX1JTTtzbTxdh3LAcUPMFxZY9sO1MzCgPq2KqUWnlT7tS3gsYyYpr@OsKize5JkhVNUQzMtlZwDMpfSZRRWcnHHHThUGaJNIHrVWAS/PCRQdLybyxFMNKG4axER7Irl689/NV@bzgeKW2caXH4dCN5waavAmXJJgu4LcLU4p4zPSYpEUR442XdAiaWrwH/GINn@@Z552ry20Z22uWURbEO2JWA8Uj6/n8Ec1KzovEYcYhYWcXfoiXrQ4OF3@pEk/vuoc9drdzmVRik3F/aM0YXep5pnA46uMLPAIRDQM4gwYu25YdKSYG@IwgkpOjYGqyMhiBHL9hFVIFUqPAV3QQYQCHuY609lYvMyJ5QjD8yU8aYlngLJymWAJg64gpTC44Uwncd5KjFUu3ximk8bFHJBnVlHVmCLNOHgTOUZVa2nkKIObTsW8F5pFXzPR2UzwtohKr8Nj6mjOvDdi1qYTV7vpMeOtudW3kHNww7wPiw1uQwwG@GcyAzcNA2SODYdYIX9BAikwFcrJ6kRejHThDNC3eXClNJDkzwgvCr@sUjkO2isGcxuBZI4HX/coHuOv7Hityss5GLfG0Plw4O0TSM7oHzPq2jSE3s6wiXq6peLFo2Xzd3JAjG83ZvjiMe0wYnNHGVLHR3IfPusetiGmI2UcLN7y0bq2oILcC3ZNepmI6/Z7pYFtGpTQkYmdTUOtJWUf9wsbdnbT3o/Oc0EWeEz5RcQuPIvlE1dqSnl7l7O3GJtx/TQvj9rtyMixyFH9YvqxsLwvN2cugG5nw8T/fCMevE7a6CiBvgGKjOsnKwL2WBiNwWdgXNmHxjCLHC4/RZoSls8RWyQ9ZTZ4Hcamlk05Vsip9HEfcDY2TDzz3lZeXyHejK36kvvLncc3ZsLwlBPyk7BzSV4fyJUN0DcgZTQWGxltV0GN@0kgNzCUk7LwHVh0YyMlUSNaMV8oZ2GEZ@LcUwxje0uIBw6SaqXDkYgiOeVJT5fRNKx1e/f19f3OfuTAYvzNY9PUBifyvqyZe/zIwXJJuGD4F7xNjtsK3psmdGtkMHOhWXKGYL87SOM@tg@J0RTu67zACUbgkozgm3gvSHPofm3@TsCjWBaQsXxj9VB/tdlfI/hGivdqA@fOCXgxhT6MMjRiY23vJn7xfqeRMV3a831ooAlMrmJYxZOsipVxXP5K1B046DfWOLexpguvKPSicu6THJkjsoW1RybgRBjI2rwClQD8PVVQgdpzaJDUG7qISibm2GIBr6OJnGJhIU0qYpJqm39XTN7fVkxG8VHIl7Ay@HfssnwID1jTThbV1Cu2everA/9c6uC78Lvw/Hsp5Vwurq336/9wGrFMg08Tj4k1ZwdTy1zISmxlTr4fUryB@5THPfg57nMe952RRg635vnoiTjEmsAeFp6LOHimGBlyj59NjSDExpSRsTNx8B4LdG93FI8hwzhmFeBE2ZTa4mwI8v2xT@nh5ecGqS52jsUHCzg8dplYC8IbbIDtVsUHYbCrSOHJCk7q8MMCMTWB@nBMwV3IabdzwsOeDpLZw3NRoDgwyFad3EJ44l2Zs@bvhy3YqL7iG6KLS9Lrks@to/bnFgEL9r60LnAEQOTwKBVMSVNlelOeje8r5kMcU@JlUxLMTmhZqKdWTOzsRyVZiPwAyQGTAtRHgG8@5M8qAcSi3YJX4OusL6/b8MfIK75E6vff9fsF@GdTh4FbW@YCopz3icfdGzA1gOOd8SEj1f0buRki25tiSCfLD99cJulZ1LsPyk@jB1gY@ApBIXGjz1VSDvv8Rh713Qrq5s9QVTlzeJshUnNEgo5X0fvV3EF/dja1llAtM1P@r3xdWL/JTPpTU0fW3gSAkZtwRcHP1PfUgfPoMPA2eYVHzmN@5TQpmdMrE/oqyJ9MRzfv90xnHVgquR1tKcUd2k86uHan3StKnQvDqL0k1wxMKI8HZngABJUknowvAevAqMOmlwZG8aJTd2DrSvIOAJp@JX1UvxQdpjhSKpfTR0789YA4fF9KKBB2u0XvNgAmhHkz34b2lje@pT1sILeU9HWx8HV9rm3meED0xnWnl@ra2qa@JFsHeOSA6SecKnpzPwhfZ4cv7HkGHeKVvfGTVArfkoijLWgToA/9f92pyd2meRQXavK3aVK79H9zg@and2f@@kX16pWZNy7LvHVNJntL5pf3Y8TNmNWLMeJKjLhdoA3zr@Djq2D/8EV8fO6BLhtOJKwbXUITFes/5K5gSg41xzupmMnEuRtBe0nvwNf4rVRe3UtcRZlbGpwQHJrHDzgftMsgD6pjYgV4yw8VI3pYbGpDHZ/h3YzoUmXz4sQ8a37PBAqEEF/3dvXjB0Um0d2KM92oN85UYxffWoh@EXd9OdQ5NKxS2EUyAsnh4Cw0FmswfNUhvTADAUspsSPjbwgWlg/Vutomz5H9nv@s/B8)

Accepts one character from stdin as an input. Outputs a T for truthy, nothing for falsey.

---

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem) (pxem.mktemp.emb.posixism, `BREAK_LOOP_WHEN_INSUFFICIENT=0`), filename only: 42 bytes.

The `\0001` is an unprintable whose codepoint is 0x01.

```
[<>+-,.].i.t@.w.c.c.z.d.a.m.-\0001.yT.o.d.a@.a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pTp7X9rKtv/nU4wRhQhJAG21YmzRouVUwaN42x6x@cUwSBQSdiYIPrhffd@1ZvLWdu@zr1ZKZj1mzXrNWjN5tNjoz9UV/cZxdTaSpFUyXdCJNrkP6GSq0cmNNvWYs3DYRCOOq9regJIzwICHgPpTn8KnJq0C3RG1gplPGTwRlRx6k6kVODdjSuZOMCLuvVZknMgd0AFhUzp0ho4NKJ7LCQ4eA6rOXCcg9sjyLRv48vGOR9gYhCSu5xN3Nh6TIXwZOmPqWhPKUS4Cn1oT1fMdCvwHpK13uUTffCeA@cjNo0Z6U4seWfMn6qJ8R45rjclsOrACqpF6tV7TqtvaZo1c9g7LHxDjxLGpywB4CLwD54Hiiiaey8h/qO@RByDQUFu3NCBn3Yv29/EjYTNQiMPomDJGqPvg@J47AZEkBkgqnUmzicXuSbW6vU1WYT0BfK3XG8RifE1C5xJdTD0/ICeHZvPkxDiUgscpxWlszx2SfX1AH3Suhvr@eo2srwu4DcJZ7uAteMjvrNn7YsiFUoSpTmOmCAL0mFQpPONQeXcpvqhLOeJy2Wl/Ny96n416tboJi0C5v5ypl9/jaVAXJz/Mw@75eeuwZ9RCpOPO5Z@r5OyyR350L8/J2ffWKbmAb4ct8qV13pKO2ietTvO0ZRSv9vbLakW71hwt@KTNNRt@n7SBZmkTTe1Xq9Wa9tjTPBz5pFlF6bDb6bU6PQPY2yNq3zvubeIezlAihIBV3GBI1li/7xK5EM0lkxeE3vp0StQ/iNoifXyGn2Lp58vVz37/Wun3S9WXKv7jf1WldPWzqu5cvxSUIpGCEXWRhNojj3RQ67Hzgq/HYpDa/nqd4y3Av2vS0JH@uWT6S1q4d9svVfyDj5RoSjEr2gWPoL@QCPTnzdwAZPJufWsiodkWSJSWSy6E@pZTw/FYgwy89LJuAGkBiyFzm6i2mHTguVQSXis8/pXTvryQZ@QiwCWlFK6dh9Fh@DBw/GAyBY9@7p2efW6f76KXCpBtMQoTCwwZV1AqFpUQmJDq8BEONhol/Q0ELQFvvAbD1OLbmh5P3WhQZtnhA09UXNsgQiFaRSlh5AzJFVF9wtc/8yEsvQm5hqDFYTs33CCRSeMfD8K4SVyiBmSwRdQOgY@HDFmCTseMZohLU4bUqkemzqBCA2dCK1N7Oqs8sCewI2RGRXjhW9PN@ExZcOCDdRip1uqbW@/eb@98IMWrvrtxXczhca/W8sSWMyaqS7bqOQCDhF5k@k9to1/S@s87/WVfKej9mp5na83vUSbLUOu1re2tnc33WzukmEF5tspGodpYtjqfn7mLEmuZwoAgEF@ShSPT4nOCwlCtpUJVaaTI0MTgm4Zs3dgDOrwdOXf344nrTf/wWTB7mC8en5oHh59bR8df2v/6enLa6Z79@/yid/k/377/@E@iLlNOMT0xIFBvg1Ep4p6Z0fNLjlFrOHtGrdpwymXlObNOhN8B/A7gW407gGfASYCy2Q0L/HiOCgyW@AqVjROlUkvPGREROS3mMvwaq1GJUoD42SX7cSTqBT6PjJtSXpAoAf4GE0qNme@SahT/mEZC18YUJ4tssUuG4EngM4EH@5tLffBjYhEEeb7lP/IMKMfpL@Fbw0dFWkqSPaaWa4IYXIiS0C3PPSopPNcg0ZDCR4k7vDUlxSJpfW/3yJfLM9Lu9Mi/L@HhrH3WIs2T81PSa52fIq4/IeoQFhixlWMG6t@i53m6UAP5Ig64mYs1K3K4yaK3Mtt3poHEWWdX8tfzSFCPkf39lJRkb68Iyf2ofVyUDlrH7Q5XxuVFyzw4NKrcEQ7OW82v5km3e2Z@@9LqmO3OxeXRUfuwjZuyQGkedM975sF59yvAERN8Mxlvn5y0jpsnQNhrHbfOEbaUxKQgEdSRYLHQCul9pRZukumsVIuz0qtkhP6VyUfpNLRKPP/Wcp0nSsYObN5QHEJcQCUhgD61vVsOfbDGDvrWPRSHUpJ0Pnd7xtZ7kW0SNcHPmAFVqAXcmSaDq1qtfm3gl53qtSFP5SysJmDbHwDm5WDVELYDMDcLq74LYZsAczKwDwCSzezQB4H9fhtAdm6WkNMOcmI52E4Iew@wh5wE4aq2cVXDHCxc1XtcFc3x3Ap5Ar3s52ChnDso5zwLq4fa2EFtLHKwcL4dnO8xBwvl/IByPmXVsh2KiRqzcqK8D1mCuHKQW14o5jaKOcnBQjHfo5iDDGwLNVzODuHMamZoE7FWskOo/kJ2CKdei4eEP/InnqEjd4R@7cHxZswIvfyK@@d1RBaNlstiHDdLKSpVSjGxAezX1wtVLGtg8vTmgzsPp1WNeoN/EZ@qqrzeSoZyFGxrg74rV94WKt54cJ2Fajy@jFeH23lScpV@Oe/fnXRZjLLCfOTYI@INCe7hsOVQBnvJxApgELvajwKLarcamZPFYoE7jRd9nQsoFHmWIMWOjxNXeClHmG7pTZ1gN@bcQntLyXDmA8QXhMwjTVDxALtkoL7xMesQK5V2XMqC8YNRFYlH/3mFYl4X9EgbfDIUFCwqcNMm5epouHQRJI6i/7QScrB5OINRTRuZE8pNucE3pWrGIGmy/ddUQ9las1HtiWgCV1XTBo@Fyti51ogNYw0GZGzdQFHLn8Vg@7Tda/banWNy3O11yQU8tE5hF7og39rQ4R51T0663xDc/PaVXHTaZ2et3q4g5X7TEOKuijVw9gbklsVCVp7hcxkBsZT@PYamaWlkDoOnnu@ElYmHny6UMAuHBdixcl6CZplakuM6gWONx49QdokRcA8oaOBv5M2BT@CpQB6ugnspuhN09pwrBCj4Exl7HhRGTC/oFT2HyR0PURM8wjE/hZjW3FrMHy2BbXsu8J1l8Zle@bSRsEYCKyK48al1/5o9J4hmaO6iMnCjH9OAwlIHznAIq4SQD2u8VdI96H2LIkCwwaWDBueojygkUvuvsI0sL/lJi1AvuBXFwydxgAS1OZlafiA86@0AEr5ZLke@CPVyCTJvBX85SyUTTEQW88hivkxYvc1aVTOsUS/A@9Pf5x5HBKgC60mXjbHiDU95GGrWmkJHDxxwHBTKpKirEpIJprFcTNeXeQfXY1hBB0@PHm9S64uSaprPdMZGpTSt8poSOrtpQYc8CzXeCtSywWNJUaazAM9RSlMPun9BBHheQQeZ/gLJfYWEZ463NI/nFIR4eAaGXBKImUAi0gRo59kDYpBhzHIYCIxgDwUd9lDqM5qMDQt6qp3DAAPHN/kOho0dnyEcvXKuYzJa0MFjfA/Xl@LmvyFfqqkTOoixI59EU0NQmTDPoCSvy4ryhqNzp4jHYxeNeFn9kmCH7XmWYb8WcQz9@y2medeP@DYLehjLH@VGmH9oBAyyyw28EbWmOUtPOA4HhAoZ@t4kfI6QBgWdp6pYM@WVwpoqVIO2KCn7Rl2xfNiwJuAXNtcSR44DEDgOwLQ87Q09D8KBR1opPoQr8uIozEu42aQiDKKKhyNs9Qk@lygOxldNlGLdeH5goqIFH0V04byJfU5NO3NtPGaHcsBxQ8xnFlj2/ZUzMKA@rYqpRaeVPu1LeCxjJimv46wqLN7kmSFU1RDMy2VnAMyl9JlFFZycccdOFQZok0getVYBL88JFB0vJvLEUw0obhrERHsiuXr9381X5vOB4pbZxpcfh0I3nBpq8CZckmC7gtwtTinjM9JikRRHjjZd0CJpavBLPKLNn@6Yp91pC@1Jm2sW0RZEeyTWPcXT6zn8Uc2KzkvEIUZhIWeXvogXLQ5Ol79o0o8uO4e9drdzUZRiU3H/KE3Ybap5JvD4IiMLPAIRDYM4A8auGxYdKeaaOIygklNjoCoyshiBXD9hFVKF0mNAF3QQoYCHuc50Nha3OrEcYXg@hyct8QxQVi4TLGHQV0gpDG4400mctxJjlcvXhumkcTEH5JlVVDWmSDMO3kSOUdVaGjnK4KZTMe@EZtHXTHQ2E7wtotLr8Jg6mjPvjJi16cTVbnrMeGtu9S3kHNww78Jig9sQgwH@m8zATcMAmWPDIVbIL0ggBaZCOVmdyIuRLpwB@jYPrpQGkvwZ4UXhl1Uqx0F7xWBuI5DM8eDjDsVj/O6O16q8nINxawydDwfePILkjP4xo65NQ@jNDJuoxxsqbiAtm1/OATHebszwBjLtMGJzRxlSx0dyH37WPGxDTEfKOFi85aN1bUEFuRfsmvQyEdetd0oD2zQooSMTOxuGWkvKPu4XNuzspr0XneeCLPCY8ouIXXgWyyeu1JTy1g5nbzE24/ppXhy225GRY5Gj@sX0Y2F5X27OXADdzIaJ//lGPHiVtNFRAn0DFBnXT1YE7LEwGoPPwLiyB41hFjlcfoo0JSyfI7ZIesps8DqMTS2bcqyQU@nDHuCsr5t45r2lvLxAvBmb9SX3l1uPb8yE4Skn5Cdh55K8NpAr66BvQMpoLDYy2q6CGveTQG5gKCdl4QpYdH09JVEjWjFfKGdhhGfi3FMMY2tTiAcOkmqlw5GIIjnlSU@X0TSsdWvn5eXd9l7kwGL8zWPT1AYn8r6smbv8yMFySbhg@B@8TY7bCt6bJnSrZDBzoVlyhmC/W0jjPrYPidEU7uu8wAlG4JKM4JW8F6Q5dL82fxDwKJYFZCzfeH2o/7rZXyV4I8V7tYFz6wS8mEIfRhkasbG2dhK/eLfdyJgu7fk@NNAEJlcxrOJJXouVcVx@JeoOHPQba5zbWNOFVxR6UTn3UY7MEdnC2iUTcCIMZG1egUoA/h4rqEDtKTRI6oYuopKJObZYwOtoIqdYWEiTipik2uafFZP3txWTUXwU8iWsDP4ZuywfwgPWtJNFNfUrW6387sA/lzr4LrwSnn8vpZzLxbX1Xv0fTiOWafBp4jGx5uxgapkLWYmtzMn3Qoo3cB/zuPu/xn3K464YaeRwa56PHolDrAnsYeG5iINnipEhd/nZ1AhCbEwZGTsTB19oge7tluIxZBjHrAKcKJtSW5wNQb4/8ik9uPjcINXF9pH4wQIOj10m1oLwBhtgO1XxgzDYVaTwZAUndfhhgZiaQH04puAu5KTbOeZhTwfJ7OG5KFDsG2SzTm4gPPGlmdPmj4MWbFRf8Ybo/IL0uuRz67D9uUXAgr0vrXMcARA5OEwFU9JUmd6UZ@O7inkfx5S4bEqC2QktC/XUKxM7e1FJFiLfQ3LApAD1EeCb9/mzSgCxaLfgFfga68trNvwx8oKXSP3@Sr9fgP82dBi4sWUuIMp5l3jcnQFTAzjeGe8zUt29kZshsr0phnSy/PDmMknPot69V34ZPcDCwCsEhcSNPldJOezzG3nUlVeoG79CVeXM4W2GSM0RCTpeRe9Vcwf92dnUWkK1zEz5v/JVYe06M@kvTR1ZewMARm7CVwp@or6nDpwHh4G3ya945Dzmd06Tkjm9MqGvgvzRdHTzbtd01oClktvRllLcof2ig2t32r2i1Dk3jNpz8pqBCeXxwAwPgKCSxJPxJWDtG3XY9NLAKF506g5sXUnuAKDpV9JH9UvRYYojpXI5feTErwfE4ftSQoGw2y16NwEwIcyb@Ta0t7zxLe1iA7mppN8bC6/rc20zxwOiN153eq6urm7oS7K5j0cOmH7CqaKb@0F4nR1e2PMMOsR398aPUim8JRFHW9AmQB/6/3qnJvc2zYN4oSb/Nk1ql/5v3qD55bszf31R/fqVmTdelnnrNZnsWzK/fT9GvBnz@sUY8UqMeLtAG@av4ONXwf7hRXx87oEuG04krBu9hCYq1n/IXcGUHGqOd1Ixk4lzO4L2kt6Cr/HXU3l1L3EVZd7S4ITg0Dx@wPmgXQZ5UB0TK8C3/FAxoofFpjbU8Sm@mxG9Xdk8PzZPm98zgQIhxNe9Vf3wXpFJ9G7FqW7UG6eqsYO3FqJfxF1fDnUODasUdpGMQHLYPw2NxRoMrzqkZ2YgYCkldmT8hmBh@VCtq23yFNnv6c/y/wE)

Accepts one character from stdin as an input. Outputs a T for truthy, nothing for falsey.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 17 bytes

```
[ "+-,.<>[]"in? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpSrFBQlFpSUllQlJlXAhQoLE3NS04tVrDm4lLSVrax0wvQUfofraCkraujZ2MXHauUmWevEPu/WqFWITexQDexWEHvPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 14 bytes

```
"+-,.()[]"i~u>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/19JW1dHT0MzOlYps67U7v9/XQA)

```
"+-,.()[]"      - Push legit characters onto the stack
          i     - Read codepoint from STDIN
           ~    - Pop stack, search stack for that codepoint, push 1|0 result
            u   - Print top of stack as a number (will be 1 or 0)
             >  - Switch stacks to avoid printing the current contents
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 18 bytes

```
inside("+-,.<>[]")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8zrzgzJVVDSVtXR8/GLjpWSfP/fyU7JQA)

- Fix+4 thanks to @JoKing

Comment: Bounty started. By the way, this is 100 because SE has silly rules saying that if you've posted  an answer, the minimum bounty is +100.

Comment: The output is always true for every input.

Comment: You should be using [`inside`](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8zrzgzJVVDSVtXR8/GLjpWSfP/fyU7JQA)

Comment: I'll award the bounty once this answer  becomes valid.

Comment: @emanresuA fixed thx to jo king, if you have already lost 100 rep for prev. Bounty you are free to not award the bounty again

Comment: @wasif I've decided to just go with only awarding on questions where I can do +50 bounties (No bounties from me, no answers from me), so if you do another answer where I can award one, I happily will - just edit it into [the answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23837/100664) in italics. I've got a bit of a backlog, so I can't start another one for three days.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 22 bytes

```
if <symbol v] contains (input) then
set [output v] to [true]
else
set [output v] to [false]
```

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/566906741/editor/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 31 bytes

```lua
print((...):match'[[%]+-.,><]')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ09PT9MqN7EkOUM9Olo1VltXT8fOJlZd8////9EA)

Prints either the inputted character (strings are always truthy) or nil (which is falsy).

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) XPG4.2/Single UNIX Specification, Version 3, POSIX:2001, 30 bytes

```c
f(c){c=!!index("+-,.<>[]",c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDoMwDADAPa8wkZBtJekHQvhIYUCmqTw0rRBDpQi@Hrj1JLxFWsskXCV1nZb19Sfrgn8M43O2Xjge7bNoIa4mfzfSsoMmBIw6JDwxOqds4LfdkcliLwhhhH6divWgHjIpczRHuwA)

Comment: nitpick: index() isn't included by the C standard, so shouldn't it be stated?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ah, well deciphered! Ok, posted the version of POSIX it's good to go on. Thanks! :-)

Comment: This is totally not necessary. `C (gcc)` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN 12 bytes

3 bytes saved thanks to  @Avi F. S.

Prompts for character and returns 1 if `true` 0 if `false`:

```
⎕∊'+-,.<>[]'
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ooz3t/6O@qY86utS1dXX0bOyiY9VBov/TuNS11bmApDKYtAGTdmBSD0wGgEkddS4A)

Comment: Keeping in form with your answer, you can shave off the first `×`, [here](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5r66tr6@ro2dhFx6o/6ugCyv4Hiv9P41LXVucCkspg0gZM2oFJPTAZACZ11LkA). Though if you just flip them around, you can do `⎕∊'+-,.<>`[]'`, [here](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ooz3t/6O@qY86utS1dXX0bOyiY9VBov/TuNS11bmApDKYtAGTdmBSD0wGgEkddS4A)!

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 31 bytes

```c
f(c){c=!!strchr("+-,.<>[]",c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDoMwDADAPa8wkZBtJekHQvgIdKhcBTw0rQIbol8P3HoSFpHWMgkfkrpu26uslawL/jGM09N64Xi2z0sL8WHyt5KWHTQhYNQh4R@jc8oGfvWOTBZ7QQgj9O@5WA/qIZMyR3O2Cw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 16 bytes

Input is STDIN. Prints `0` (Ruby truthy) or `nil` (falsy).

Annoyingly, it seems like Ruby demands that both `[` and `]` be escaped in the character class regex.

```ruby
p~/[+-,.<>\[\]]/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6BOP1pbV0fPxi4mOiY2Vv//f20uZS4bLjsuPa4ALp1/@QUlmfl5xf9183IA)

Comment: That's apparently because Ruby allows nested character classes.

Answer (score 0):

## JS, 26 bytes

```js
c=>'+-,.<>[]'.indexOf(c)+1
```

## x86_16 machine code, 40 bytes

Outputs '0' (false) or '1' (true) on the screen.

```
bb1f 7cb1 5080 3f00 7409 380f 7409 83c3
01eb f2b0 30eb 02b0 31b4 0ecd 10eb fe2b
2d2c 2e3c 3e5b 5d00
```

**To boot, pad it to 510 bytes with zeros and add 55aa at the end!

This means "uncomment the last two assembly lines and rebuild".**

Ungolfed (compilable, compile using nasm -fbin -o is-bf is-bf.asm):

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bx, string
mov cl, 'P' ; the character
loop_:
    cmp byte [bx], 0
    je false
    cmp byte [bx], cl
    je true
    add bx, 1
    jmp loop_
false:
    mov al, '0'
    jmp print
true:
    mov al, '1'
print:
    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h
jmp $ ; hang forever



string: db "+-,.<>[]", 0
; times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
; dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: you don't have to make the assembly snippet bootable, you can aswell write a callable function

Comment: I like bootable snippets more because I can boot them in QEMU and see the results :)

Comment: this makes your code bigger, though.

Answer (score 0):

## LaTeX, 52 bytes

```latex
\usepackage{xstring}\def\f#1{\IfSubStr{[]+-.,}#1x{}}
```

Defined a macro `\f` that takes one argument and expands to `x` if the input is a brainfuck instruction and to nothing if not. Assumes there is only one character in the argument.

### Explanation

```latex
\usepackage{xstring}  % load the xstring package for the IfSubStr macro
\def\f#1{             % define a macro \f that takes 1 argument
  \IfSubStr{[]+-.,}#1 % test if the second argument is a substring of the first
    x                 % if it is a substring expand to x
    {}                % else expand to nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

*-2 bytes by treating as a self-contained program instead of a block.*

```
"+-<>[].,"q#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X0lb18YuOlZPR6lQ@f9/bQA)

Returns -1 if not a brainfuck character, anything else if so.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 15 bytes

```perl
$_=y/+,.<>[]-//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rZSX1tHz8YuOlZXX///f20uA65orlguGy67f/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 20 bytes

```java
"<[+.,-]>"::contains
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZC7DoJAEEV7vmKyFfjYDxC10IrCitJQDMvDVdg1u4OJQb8dV0RNrAy3mWRyzs1kjnjB@TE7decmraQAUaG1sEOpoPU8cJGKclOgyCFq@8UzqdZVjgqk3RjHFo04bQ9o/JiMVCWIIOzR@6ti6LaE5MZFywxqZw30PgE0pQ3gWx@BhFXHlvspn82TNVsshFbkFNuF3oeKr5bymuuG@NkVUaV8yX8vYhMWDNf870xHOOsRzq133q@6dw8)

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 21 bytes

```lua
find(c,"[[%]+-.,><]")
```

Returns `1` for truthy, or nothing for falsey.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z8tMy9FI1lHKTpaNVZbV0/HziZWSfP///9K2koA)